# Implementing named events on linux

Tags: c++, linux, synchronization

I have implemented the named event on linux using named semaphore, i have achieved the functionality, somehow, with some acceptable limitations, however, unlike named events on windows,, if my process crashes the named semaphore is not deleted automatically.

How can i resolve this issue, or is there any other option to implement named event on linux.

Comment: Why not wrap the events in a class and delete them in the destructor?

Comment: yes that can be done, but in case of abnormal termination, segmentation faults the problem remains.